# How to forward declare a namespace with class and inheriting the class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, qt5

I'm currently trying to build a helper class for my QT ui-file implementation.

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
    class Form;
}

class Implementation : public QWidget, public Ui::Form {
    virtual void implement();
}
```

I'm leaving the standard name "Form" for it to work. Mocing is done via cmake.

```
#include "implementation.h"
#include "MyDesignedWidget.h"

class ImplementedWidgetA : public Implementation, public Ui::Form{
    ImplementedWidgetA();
}
```

My cpp should look like this:

```
#include "implementedwidgeta.h"

ImplementedWidgetA::ImplementedWidgetA() {
    implement();
}

ImplementedWidgetA::implement() : QWidget(), Ui::Form() {
    ...
}
```

My original code has a lot of parameters inside the `implement()` function, and I want to build a class so that I don't have to copy paste it into every header, making it easier to edit and debug.

I'm fairly new to C++, so reaching this point took a few hours of trial and error. I currently get the following error message:

> error C2011: 'Ui_Form': 'class' type redefinition

Somewhat expected, but the compiler doesn't allow me to skip the forward declaration of `Ui`.

Any idea how I can solve this, or do I need to put the declaration into every header?

Comment: Base class should be complete...

Comment: `implement()` is not a constructor... so  `: QWidget(), Ui::Form()` is wrong.

Comment: Warning: Calling virtual method `implement();` in constructor would call it non-virtually.

Comment: If you want mocking, you should probably use member instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Your forward declaration is correct, but forward declarations in C++ are primarily used for pointer members (smart pointers, references are fine too). The class declaration has to fully declare the object layout in memory, so having a pointer class field `Form* form` to a forward-declared Form would be fine, because the size of the pointer is fixed. Having a plain Form member (or also inheriting from it which acts as extension with Form's own members) will affect the layout and size of Implementation in an unknown way, so it is forbidden. One reason for that is that when multiple .cpp files include the same `Implementation.h` file they can be compiled independently in parallel, and they have to exactly agree on the implementation object size/layout.

When it comes to duplicating the `implement()` method signature when implementing it in a subclass, yes, unfortunately you have to do it, and it has to be redeclared with an `override` keyword in `implementedwidgeta.h`:

```cpp
class ImplementedWidgetA : public Implementation {
    void implement() override;
}
```